# three.js: THREE.Vector3.sub() acting weirdly

Tags: javascript, three.js

Why does THREE.Vector3.sub return (0,0,0) in this scenario?

```
p0 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 100, 50 );
p1 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 50, 100 );
dummy = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
p1_relative_to_p0 = dummy.sub(p1, p0);
console.log(p1_relative_to_p0);
```

this is the sub function from the THREE.Vector3's prototype:

```
sub: function ( a, b ) {
    this.x = a.x - b.x;
    this.y = a.y - b.y;
    this.z = a.z - b.z;
    return this;
},
```

console-output:

> THREE.Vector3
>   x: 0
>   y: 0
>   z: 0

Why isn't the output (0, 50, -50) ?

The code can be seen in action here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2070405/webgl_lines_splines_jon.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fell victim of the `console.log` caveat. In Chrome, a logged object is evaluated *when you expand it*, not when you log it.

Due to `return this`, it is true that `p1_relative_to_p0 === dummy`. You're updating `dummy` later on and thus also `p1_relative_to_p0`, because objects are shared in JavaScript. When you expand the object, you're effectively reading `dummy`'s contents, which have been set to `0, 0, 0` in the meantime.

Try setting a breakpoint instead of the log to halt execution to observe the right values.

Comment: Or try this `console.log(p1_relative_to_p0.x, p1_relative_to_p0.y, p1_relative_to_p0.z )`.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to duplicate the behavior [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KuZLZ/), but it worked exactly as you intended. Any chance you were just accidentally reading values from the wrong area?

Comment: Now I have moved all console.log statements, except one, into comments. The one left is the one you see in the code above. It still says 0,0,0. :(

Comment: You can see my code in action here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2070405/webgl_lines_splines_jon.html